# How Can I calculate this Infinite Product?

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, infinite-product

I would like to calculate the value of this infinite product:
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
According to Wolfram, it seems to converge at around $3.514$, but I have no idea how to start proving this. I have virtually no experience evaluating infinite products.

Any hints? Please don't hand me the entire answer... I would like to try to do some of it on my own.

Comment: take the logarithm of the product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given product equals

$$ \exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\exp\left[\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{mn^{m+1}}\right]=\exp\left[\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}\zeta(m+1)}{m}\right]$$
that can be rearranged as
$$ 2\,\exp\left[\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\left(\zeta(m+1)-1\right)\right]$$

Thanks to [user1952009](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/user1952009), by exploiting the integral representation for the $\zeta$ function we have that the product can be written as 
$$\exp\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\gamma+\Gamma(0,x)+\log(x)}{e^x-1}\,dx\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\exp\left[-\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-e^{-x})\log(1-e^{-x})\frac{dx}{x}\right]\approx e^{5/4} $$

I doubt there is a "nice" closed form, however.

Comment: This is where I got, but wasn't sure if this was the end of the line.  Coming from you, I suppose it probably is.

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend any less messy infinite product problems that I could try? Or a good online resource where I can find some?

Comment: @Frpzzd: this exercise is nice (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304650/how-to-calculate-product) and has been posted just few minutes ago.

Comment: @Frpzzd: anyway, the main trick is very often the same: by applying a logarithm any (convergent) infinite product is converted into a (convergent) series.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Frpzzd Telescoping products, Euler products, and products found by taking logarithms are the first that come to my head.

Comment: I obtain $m! \zeta(m+1) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^m }{e^x-1}dx$ and $$ \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} \frac{\zeta(m+1)}{m}= \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x} \log(1-e^{-x})dx$$

Comment: @user1952009: I would say $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\gamma+\Gamma(0,x)+\log x}{e^x-1}\,dx \approx \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-3x/4}\,dx = \frac{4}{3}$$ instead. A $m!$ is missing in your LHS.

Comment: Aren't they the same ? I have integrated by parts $\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1} \frac{\zeta(m+1)}{m} = \int_0^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1}\frac{x^m}{m!m} \frac{1 }{e^x-1}dx \\=\int_0^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m}\frac{x^{m-1}}{m!} \log(1-e^{-x})dx $

Comment: @user1952009: I haven't checked the steps but the involved series is positive while your previously mentioned integral is quite clearly negative, something does not match.

Comment: @user1952009: ok, they are the same up to the sign. $\frac{5}{4}$ is a much better approximation than $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: $\displaystyle = \exp\left(\int_{0}^{1}{H_{t} \over t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: true, and that is a nice and compact representation. Feel free to add it to my answer, if you like.

Comment: I'm writing an answer right now. At this stage, I'm struggling to find a 'nice' approximation.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mc{Q}_{N} \equiv
> \prod_{n = 1}^{N}\pars{n + 1 \over n}^{1/n}\,,\qquad\lim_{N \to \infty}\mc{Q}_{N} =\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}
\ln\pars{\mc{Q}_{N}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n}\,\ln\pars{n + 1 \over n} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over n + t} =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 1 + t}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}\pars{{1 \over n + 1} - {1 \over n + 1 + t}}
{\dd t \over t}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{H_{N} -\sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1}{1 \over n + 1 + t}}
{\dd t \over t}\qquad\pars{~H_{z}: Harmonic\ Number~}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{H_{N} -
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n + 1 + t} - {1 \over n + N + 1 + t}}}
{\dd t \over t} =
\int_{0}^{1}{H_{N} - H_{t + N} + H_{t} \over t}\dd t
\\[5mm] & \implies \bbx{\lim_{N \to \infty}\ln\pars{\mc{Q}_{N}} =
\int_{0}^{1}{H_{t} \over t}\dd t}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{n + 1 \over n}^{1/n} =
\exp\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{H_{t} \over t}\dd t}}}\,,\qquad
\pars{\substack{\mbox{It seems a 'closed' expression,}\\
                \mbox{beyond this one}\\[2mm] 
               \mbox{is}\ {\large highly\ unlikely}}}
$$

> A 'numerical approach' yields $\ds{\approx 3.5175 \approx \expo{5.031/4}}$.